# What does the "required" keyword in Swift mean?

Tags: swift

Take the following example:

```
class A {
    var num: Int

    required init(num: Int) {
        self.num = num
    }
}

class B: A {
    func haveFun() {
        println("Woo hoo!")
    }
}
```

I've marked `A`'s `init` function as `required`. What exactly does this mean? I completely omitted it in the subclass `B` and the compiler doesn't complain at all. How is it required, then?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

See ["Automatic Initializer Inheritance"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_335):

> **Rule 1** If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it
>   automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> **Rule 2** If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its
>   superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per
>   rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its
>   definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass
>   convenience initializers.

In your example, the subclass `B` does not define any initializers on its own, therefore it
*inherits* all initializers from `A`, including the required initializer.
The same is true if `B` defines only convenience initializers
(now updated for **Swift 2**):

```
class B: A {

    convenience init(str : String) {
        self.init(num: Int(str)!)
    }

    func haveFun() {
        print("Woo hoo!")
    }
}
```

But if the subclass defines any designated (= non-convenience) initializer then it
does not inherit the superclass initializers anymore. In particular the required
initializer is not inherited, so this does not compile:

```
class C: A {

    init(str : String) {
        super.init(num: Int(str)!)
    }

    func haveFun() {
        print("Woo hoo!")
    }
}
// error: 'required' initializer 'init(num:)' must be provided by subclass of 'A'
```

If you remove the `required` from `A`'s init method then class `C`
compiles as well.

Comment: So, what does the "required" keyword actually do?

Comment: @AndrewPaulSimmons: It requires that all subclasses implement that method – explicitly or by inheritance. What I tried to explain here – because OP was apparently confused about that – is why class `B` from the question satisfies the requirement by inheritance, and I gave an example where it must be implemented explicitly.

Comment: @MartinR It requires all subclasses to implement that *initializer*, specifically. Although, it would be super nice if we could use it for arbitrary methods as well... that way, we could create something sort of like Java's abstract methods, e.g., `required func doSomething() { fatalError() }`

Comment: @MartinR please ans this question also.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592603/swift-initialization-rule-confusion

Answer (score 31):

The `required` keyword means that inheriting classes must provide an implementation of the method. However, the language makes an exception for required initializers:

> You do not have to provide an explicit implementation of a required initializer if you can satisfy the requirement with an inherited initializer.

[Reference to the documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_351)

Comment: Isn't that the same for a non-`required` initializer? What would be a case where the two differ?

Comment: Not sure what it was then, but `required` now, can only be used for initializers.

Answer (score 4):

“The use of the required modifier ensures that you provide an explicit or inherited implementation of the initializer requirement on all subclasses of the conforming class, such that they also conform to the protocol.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l