# Use of required keyword in UIKit file

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently learning Swift and this is likely a stupid question, but I cannot seem to find an answer to it despite thoroughly looking around.

I'm aware that if you put the `required` keyword in front of an initializer, it means that it is required by any subclasses. When learning that `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` initializer that is required for subclasses of UIViewController, I noticed when going into the UIViewController.h file, there is no required keyword in front of that initializer there. This probably has something to do with how the UIKit framework is set up, but I'm not sure.

Why is it that the `required` keyword wouldn't be there and, come to think of it, why don't any of the functions in UIViewController.h have bodies to them? My understanding was that Swift does not use header files like Objective-C does.

Comment: try see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923123/what-does-the-required-keyword-in-swift-mean), for `UIKit` class, some class doesn't meant for subclassing (you can, but the doc said no), it's init is private, so it said you have to add a `required init`, example for `UIAlertView`

Comment: UIViewController.h is written in Objective-C. That is correct, that Swift does not need a header file. Swift was designed to be interoperable with Objective-C API's. There are initializers in Objective-C that can return nil, one of which is the `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.