# Swift Initialization Rule Confusion

Tags: swift, initialization

Rule 1

If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.

**Confusion:** I provided one designated initializer in sub class. Its means no super class designated initializer will comes down to subclass. But I still needs to write **override** keyword to provide implementation of any super class designated initializer in sub class(which means super class designated init comes down to sub class). Rule 1 says if I provided subclass designated initializer then super class designated won't comes down. (Override only makes sense if we did not provided any designated init for sub class.)

```
class Food{
    var name : String
    init(foodName :String) {
        self.name = foodName
    }
}

class RecipieIngredient : Food{
    var quantity : Int
    init(fName :String, quantity :Int) {
        self.quantity = quantity
        super.init(foodName: fName)
    }

    override convenience init (foodName :String){
        self.init(fName: foodName, quantity: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the superclass and subclass you're referring to? It's not quite clear specifically what you're asking.

Comment: I added code to question. @SørenMortensen

Answer (score -2):

It's because init() is not a protected method. So, if you define an init() method in the subclass, the compiler doesn't know whether you mean the init() method of the superclass, or the subclass. 'override' clears this up.

Comment: What do you mean by "protected method"? Swift doesn't have a `protected` access level. The `override` keyword isn't to disambiguate methods – it's simply to make it explicit that you're providing an override, and allows the compiler to check that the superclass has a matching declaration.

Comment: You're right. I used the term 'protected' because Swift doesn't have a similar keyword. As for disambiguation, yes it does. Try creating any superclass, with a subclass that declares a method with the same signature.

Comment: There's no disambiguation because there's no ambiguity. In cases where the call is dynamically dispatched, the class' vtable is used at runtime in order to lookup the correct implementation. In cases where the call is statically dispatched, the compiler simply looks in the declaration of the type to find the implementation to dispatch to.

Comment: brothers, Override is required only when a method or initializer is inherited from super class and we providing its implementation in sub class.  But in my case, according to rule 1. no designated initializer would be inherited. then why override. There is no need to use Override unless sub class did not inherited initializer from its super class.

Comment: @AabanTariqMurtaza Overriding by definition means that you're not inheriting the superclass' implementation – you're providing your own.

Comment: 100% true.
Override keyword is used when you are not willing to use super class implementation.
and wants to use your new implementation in Subclass.
But rule 1 says, no designated initializer would goes down(won't inherit) to Subclass in my case. So what to override then??
Read my last line twice please.